# Both-ends authenticated Docker Registry Proxy using Nexus

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

I am running Sonatype Nexus as a private docker-registry with ldap based auth ( or the relevant part, every user / server has its own authentication ).

I want to setup a second nexus server which will be a docker-registry proxy (cache/forward) to be used with `--registry-mirror`, mirroring the private registry stated above.

### What i tried

I configere a docker registry proxy:
[image]
with a private registry as backend
[image]
and authentication towards the backend ( is that actually the right assumption?
[image]

and i configured a ssl-offloader as usual form https://proxy.domain.tld to they nexus docker-proxy port ( 10090 )

Then i configured the docker-engine with --registr-mirror=https://proxy.mydomain.tld

And used `docker login https://proxy.mydomain.tld` i could use the credentials i have in my ldap correctly, but since both the backend as also the proxy share the same ldap server, i am not sure against which i authed.

### Problems/Questions:

a) I need to make the forward registry proxy authenticated "per user based"
b) can the proxy access the private registry authenticated ( using service account )

Does docker login in the case above actually authentiactes with the proxy or with the underlying private registry?

Does this setup work at all? Did i make a conceptual mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're asking that if you have a scenario like user->Nexus A->Nexus B, can Nexus A forward the credentials on to Nexus B?

If so, the answer is no. Nexus A would have its own credentials used to authenticate to Nexus B. Since Nexus A is trying to represent potentially the full contents of what is available in Nexus B, it may required elevated privileges to fetch content to satisfy the demands of all the users of A.

You should be able to structure A and B to serve the same content based on permissions though, just allow A to fetch it all from B.

Comment: Well the last screenshot i used, is actuall a service user so A does auth with B for the "full namespace" - no perms, while A itself has authentication enabled using LDAP with content selectors and all the things i used before on the old non-proxy node. As mentioned, i authed against A, but pulling does not work. It still tries to pull from B directly. the point is, B has domain: private.domain.tld(B) and so do the images like private.domain.tld/consul .. so whhen i pull i do `docker pull private.domain.tld/consul` and instead of using `public.domain.tld` (A) it pulls from B (and fails).

Comment: This sounds more like docker is selecting the wrong repo instead of the repos having trouble connecting/authenticating.

Comment: well there was nothing to really do wrong, i set `--registry-mirror=public.domain.tld` and restarted the docker enging, verified the setting with `docker info | grep mirror` .. so there is not much to really do here, so i assume(d) it is rather on the nexus side.

Comment: The repos proxy, they don't do redirects, so if your docker client is talking to B directly, then something is misconfigured in Docker, or in your dns.